# TextField always on the screen even if I change tab

Tags: swift, uikit

I've tab bar in my project, I want to add a textfield top of tabbar which will be always on the screen just like it's on safari, I tried to create it in a viewControllerFirst, but it only works on ViewControllerFirst any ideas ?